# Origin of the word or slur pisshead in British vocabulary

Tags: meaning

I have read the definitions for "taking a piss" etc but in many recent films out of Great Britain I have heard what appears to be a very vulagar reference to to anyone from the old Indian sub-continent (I am assuming) as a pisshead. It's my guess one wouldn't wish to say that to anyones face. What is the origin of this word and is it the insult directed at the race I assume it is? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to check your assumption that it's directed exclusively at subcontinentals... I've certainly heard it used, by Englishmen, directed at Irishmen, Scots, Germans, Americans... and other Englishmen.  It's an insult, sure, but I don't think it's a racial slur.

Comment: Also, "to take _the_ piss" is very different from (if I were British I would say "different to") "taking _a_ piss".  "Taking _a_ piss" is just urination; "taking _the_ piss" is a shorter version of "taking the piss (or mickey) _out of_" someone or something, in other words to cut them down to size via ridicule or sarcasm.  Again, scatological but not racial.

Comment: I would guess that it's a slightly milder version of  "shithead".

Comment: Sanitized for your convenience!

Comment: The term means that someone is a drunkard. It is nothing whatsoever to do with race.https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pisshead&oq=pisshead&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1717j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Right. I once had to have the common idiom for incompetence "He couldn't organize a pissup in a brewery" explained to me by a native. A pissup is a party where one gets pissed, i.e, drunk. And that explains the last line of the Pythons' Philosophers Song, too.

Answer (score 1):

The term has two meanings; its original usage for a heavy drinker appears to be an early 20th c. expression from New Zeland, while the later usage for a stupid bore is an AmE one from the ‘70s/80s. The term doesn’t appear to have or have had a racial connotation.

Eric Patridge  [A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA890&lpg=PA890&dq=pisshead%20origin&source=bl&ots=_3KymOnNZL&sig=AxpV1TTzcTdY59or9IYOj-DQjQs&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH_dO0-_7XAhWIbRQKHWTOAMw4ChDoAQgyMAY#v=onepage&q=pisshead%20origin&f=false) defines pisshead as:

> A habitually heavy drinker, an alcoholic.
>
> ***Perhaps of New Zeland  origin, early 20th century***, by 1955 also British

[The Dictionary of American Slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pisshead) gives a different connotation of the term:

> A despicable person; a stupid bore; asshole: who made such a pisshead of herself (1970s+)

The [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/fuhbvsy) defines both usages:

piss-head n.

> 1. [1950s+] a heavy drinker; also in attrib. use [piss n. (3b) + -head sfx (4)].
> 2. [1980s+] an obnoxious person [piss n. (1) + -head sfx (4)].

In heavy drinker *piss* refers to:

> [1910s+] *any sort of weak or otherwise unpalatable drink, whether alcoholic or non-alcoholic.*

while *head*  refers to

> [1920s+] *used in var. combs. meaning a habitual user of a drug or a particular drink, e.g. a-head n.*